# Failing over on Multiple IP Address

Tags: odp.net, odp.net-managed

Developed an application on the client side that accesses an oracle 12c database server using ODP.NET.  I have 2 network adapters on both client and the server.  The server is listening on both network rails on different ports.

If I pull a network cable from the server side the client takes about 21 seconds for it to failover to the other network rail in order to talk to the database.  How do I speed this up?  I've used TCP.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, TRANSPORT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, and CONNECTION_TIMEOUT but nothing seems to apply.  I've applied the TCP.CONNECT_TIMEOUT in both sqlnet.ora and application level but nothing works.  The TNSPING and sqlplus works fine and fails over according to the timeout specified.

It really seems like OPD.NET isn't honoring a lot of things inside the Description section.  Out of curiosity I've tested other things like putting FAILOVER=off and it still fails over.  I've also placed the description section in the connection string under the "data source" tag.  Still nothing.  Is there a bug in ODP.NET?

Please help.
-david

---

Client:

```
DBSVR =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (RETRY_COUNT = 0)
    (LOAD_BALANCE = off)
    (FAILOVER = on)
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.11)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.2.11)(PORT = 1526))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = DBSVR)
      (FAILOVER_MODE =
        (TYPE = select)
        (METHOD = basic)
      )
    )
  )
```

---

Settings in both sqlnet.ora and app.config:

```
TCP.CONNECT_TIMEOUT = 3
TRANSPORT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT = 3
CONNECTION TIMEOUT = 60
```

---

Excerpt from trace file:

```
2017-02-26 16:21:27.818678 TID:1   (CFG) (SQLNET)   SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES : (none)
2017-02-26 16:21:27.820678 TID:1   (CFG) (SQLNET)   TRACE_LEVEL_CLIENT : SUPPORT
2017-02-26 16:21:27.820678 TID:1   (CFG) (SQLNET)   TRACE_DIRECTORY_CLIENT : C:\OracleTrace
2017-02-26 16:21:27.820678 TID:1   (CFG) (SQLNET)   TRACE_FILE_CLIENT : client_trace.log
2017-02-26 16:21:27.820678 TID:1   (CFG) (SQLNET)   DIAG_ADR_ENABLED : OFF
2017-02-26 16:21:27.822678 TID:1   (CFG) (ENV)      Machine Name : CASGUI2
2017-02-26 16:21:27.822678 TID:1   (CFG) (ENV)      User Name : aimscsadmin
2017-02-26 16:21:27.822678 TID:1   (CFG) (ENV)      OS Version : Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1
2017-02-26 16:21:27.822678 TID:1   (CFG) (ENV)      64-bit OS : True
2017-02-26 16:21:27.822678 TID:1   (CFG) (ENV)      64-bit Process : False
2017-02-26 16:21:27.822678 TID:1   (CFG) (ENV)      .NET Runtime Version : 4.0.30319.42000
2017-02-26 16:21:27.822678 TID:1   (CFG) (VER)      Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver Version : 4.121.2.0
2017-02-26 16:21:27.822678 TID:1   (CFG) (VER)      Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver Informational Version : 4.121.2.20141216 ODAC RELEASE 3
2017-02-26 16:21:27.822678 TID:1   (CFG) (.NET)     TraceLevel : 7
2017-02-26 16:21:27.822678 TID:1   (CFG) (.NET)     TRANSPORT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT : 6
2017-02-26 16:21:27.822678 TID:1   (CFG) (.NET)     TRACE_FILE_CLIENT : client_trace.log
2017-02-26 16:21:27.822678 TID:1   (CFG) (.NET)     DIAG_ADR_ENABLED : OFF
2017-02-26 16:21:27.822678 TID:1   (CFG) (.NET)     TCP.CONNECT_TIMEOUT : 3
2017-02-26 16:21:27.822678 TID:1   (CFG) (.NET)     TRACE_DIRECTORY_CLIENT : C:\OracleTrace
2017-02-26 16:21:27.822678 TID:1   (CFG) (.NET)     TRACE_LEVEL_CLIENT : SUPPORT
2017-02-26 16:21:27.822678 TID:1   (CFG) (.NET)     SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES : (none)
2017-02-26 16:21:27.823679 TID:1   (CFG) (TNSNAMES) DBSVR : (DESCRIPTION =(RETRY_COUNT = 0)(LOAD_BALANCE = off)(FAILOVER = on)(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.11)(PORT = 1521))(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.2.11)(PORT = 1526)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = DBSVR)(FAILOVER_MODE =(TYPE = select)(METHOD = basic))))
2017-02-26 16:21:27.826679 TID:1   (CFG) (SQLNET)   FilePath : C:\oracle\product\12.1.0\client_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora
2017-02-26 16:21:27.826679 TID:1   (CFG) (TNSNAMES) FilePath : C:\oracle\product\12.1.0\client_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
2017-02-26 16:21:27.826679 TID:1   (PUB) (ENT) OracleConnection.ctor()
2017-02-26 16:21:27.829679 TID:1   (PRI) (ENT) (CP) ConnectionString.GetCS()
2017-02-26 16:21:27.831679 TID:1   (PRI) (ENT) (CP) ConnectionString.ctor()
2017-02-26 16:21:27.834679 TID:1   (PRI) (ENT) (CP) ConnectionString.Parse()
2017-02-26 16:21:27.837679 TID:1   (PRI) (ENT) (CP) ConnectionString.SetProperty()
2017-02-26 16:21:27.837679 TID:1   (PRI) (EXT) (CP) ConnectionString.SetProperty()
2017-02-26 16:21:27.837679 TID:1   (PRI) (ENT) (CP) ConnectionString.SetProperty()
2017-02-26 16:21:27.837679 TID:1   (PRI) (EXT) (CP) ConnectionString.SetProperty()
2017-02-26 16:21:27.837679 TID:1   (PRI) (ENT) (CP) ConnectionString.SetProperty()
2017-02-26 16:21:27.837679 TID:1   (PRI) (EXT) (CP) ConnectionString.SetProperty()
2017-02-26 16:21:27.837679 TID:1   (PRI) (ENT) (CP) ConnectionString.SetProperty()
2017-02-26 16:21:27.837679 TID:1   (PRI) (EXT) (CP) ConnectionString.SetProperty()
2017-02-26 16:21:27.837679 TID:1   (PRI) (EXT) (CP) ConnectionString.Parse()
2017-02-26 16:21:27.837679 TID:1   (PRI) (EXT) (CP) ConnectionString.ctor()
2017-02-26 16:21:27.837679 TID:1   (PRI) (EXT) (CP) ConnectionString.GetCS()
2017-02-26 16:21:27.838679 TID:1   (PUB) (EXT) OracleConnection.ctor()
2017-02-26 16:21:27.873681 TID:1   (PUB) (ENT) OracleConnection.Open() (conid=45028263) (state=Closed) (sessid=0) (implid=0) (pooling=T) (txnid=n/a)
2017-02-26 16:21:27.874681 TID:1   (PRI) (ENT) (CP) OracleConnectionDispenser`3..cctor()
2017-02-26 16:21:27.875681 TID:1   (PRI) (EXT) (CP) OracleConnectionDispenser`3..cctor()
2017-02-26 16:21:27.875681 TID:1   (PRI) (ENT) (CP) OracleConnectionDispenser`3.Get()
2017-02-26 16:21:27.876682 TID:1   (PRI) (ENT) (CP) PoolManager`3.ctor()
2017-02-26 16:21:27.877682 TID:1   (PRI) (EXT) (CP) PoolManager`3.ctor()
2017-02-26 16:21:27.878682 TID:1   (PRI) (ENT) (CP) PoolManager`3.Initialize() (constr=data source=dbsvr;user id=USR1;Connection Timeout=60;)
2017-02-26 16:21:27.878682 TID:1   (PRI) (ENT) (CP) ConnectionString.Secure()
2017-02-26 16:21:27.879682 TID:1   (PRI) (EXT) (CP) ConnectionString.Secure()
2017-02-26 16:21:27.882682 TID:1   (PRI) (EXT) (CP) PoolManager`3.Initialize() (pmid=56648283) (constr=data source=dbsvr;user id=USR1;Connection Timeout=60;)
2017-02-26 16:21:27.882682 TID:1   (PRI) (BUF) (OBP.CTOR) (poolid:40072506) (OracleConnectionDispenser`3.GetPM)
2017-02-26 16:21:27.884682 TID:1   (PRI) (ENT) (CP) OraclePoolManager.Get()
2017-02-26 16:21:27.887682 TID:1   (PRI) (ENT) (CP) PoolManager`3.Get() (txnid=n/a) (bForceMatch=F)
2017-02-26 16:21:27.889682 TID:1   (PRI) (ENT) (CP) PoolManager`3.CreateNewPR() (txnid=n/a)
2017-02-26 16:21:28.027690 TID:1   (PRI) (ENT) TimeStamp.GetLocalTZOffset()
2017-02-26 16:21:28.027690 TID:1   (PRI) (EXT) TimeStamp.GetLocalTZOffset()
2017-02-26 16:21:28.029690 TID:1   (PRI) (ENT) (CP) ConnectionString.GetStringFromSecureString()
2017-02-26 16:21:28.029690 TID:1   (PRI) (EXT) (CP) ConnectionString.GetStringFromSecureString()
2017-02-26 16:21:28.031690 TID:6   (PRI) (ENT) (CP) PoolManager`3.CreateNewPRThreadFunc()
2017-02-26 16:21:28.033691 TID:6   (PRI) (SVC) (ENT) OracleConnectionImpl.Connect() (oper=open) (aff=n/a) (inst=) (affmatch=n/a) (sessid=-1:-1) (F;F;F;;N) (pmid=56648283)
2017-02-26 16:21:28.034691 TID:6   (PRI) (BUF) (COBP.CTOR) (poolid:1) (parentpoolid:40072506) (OracleConnectionImpl.Connect)
2017-02-26 16:21:49.046892 TID:6   (PRI) (BUF) (ALLOCATION) (bufid:1)
```

Comment: It looks like you are using Managed ODP.NET? If so, the first thing to do is make sure that the TNSNAMES.ORA and SQLNET.ORA are being picked up. I would start by moving those files into the same directory as your .EXE, remove TNS_ADMIN from any config file and then restart the app to see if that helps. Next, I would upgrade to the latest managed ODP.NET as many networking related enhancements have been made since the version you are using.

Comment: Thanks Christian for the suggestion.  I've checked and do have the latest version.  All ora files are being picked up by testing other settings, but just for fun I did move files to local folder where exe resides but to no avail...  Still scratching head...

Comment: Your trace file indicates you are using ODAC Rel 3. Please upgrade to ODAC release 4. You can get the very latest ODP.NET managed from nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/

Comment: To add to my comment above, it is probably best to try only the nuget release. The ODACr4 available on OTN is too old and doesn't contain some of the later fixes that might apply here. The Nuget release is the newest.

Comment: That's weird.  I used my nuget manager to get the latest.  Ok, thanks. I'll grab it today.

Answer (score 0):

You provided the trace for the main pool thread. Can you also provide the trace file of the connection establishment thread, so we can see what it is hanging on?

Sorry, wouldve put this as a comment instead of an answer, but SO wouldn't let me.

Note, you are correct. ODP.Managed does not support (failover=). ODP.Managed only supports failover (does not support address_list load balancing), so the ONLY purpose of an address_list is failover.

Also, ODP.Managed does not YET support retries (retry_count and retry_delay).

Comment: Any chance you can tell me how to get the connection establishment thread trace?  I've been using the trace level = 7.

Comment: Actually, hadn't noticed that you had a different thread at the end. It may be that there wasn't much tracing in the connection establishment thread for ODACv3. As Christian said, can you try it with ODACr4 and see if it helps, either for the failover or for the tracing?